# Can I set two values for a submit button?

Tags: html, forms, form-submit, submit-button

***Note:*** This is a rewrite of an old post to clarify what was being asked.

Let's suppose I have a single form that displays a set of rows (for example, lines in an order), and I want to place a "delete" button besides each row, but unfortunately I can't create a single form for every row.

In addition let's say that the form goes to a "generic action route" that is the "editCart" controller.

For the sake of the example, let's assume in the form there are several other actions, like for example adding one to the quantity.

This has to be done with multiple submit buttons within the same form.

If it was only one single row, it is easy, just add a name/value to the button and boom! done!.

```
<form action="/process-edition" method="post">
    <div>My nice things</div>
    <button type="submit" name="subAction" value="delete">Delete</button>
    <button type="submit" name="subAction" value="addOne">+1</button>
</form>
```

This is saying "hey, controller of the action `/process-edition`, I'm going to make the subAction `delete`". Or "the subAction `addOne`".

But when we have multiple rows, you need to say something like "delete THIS product" or "add one of THIS product".

In this case you need that the button submits like two values: a) the subAction, b) the id of the product to be edited.

```
<form action="/process-edition" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Product 1234: 'orange'
            <button type="submit" name="subAction" value1???="delete" value2???=1234>Delete</button>
            <button type="submit" name="subAction" value1???="addOne" value2???=1234>+1</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            Product 6789: 'lemmon'
            <button type="submit" name="subAction" value1???="delete" value2???=6789>Delete</button>
            <button type="submit" name="subAction" value1???="addOne" value2???=6789>+1</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I think in this case `delete` and `addOne` is what the original post was asking as a "statically assigned value" and the `1234` and `6789` would be the "hidden" values that come from the database. The button "knows" about the Id but does not display the Id itself.

Of course this could be resolved by setting multiple forms to several different controllers with hidden fields in each form. But let's assume you are constricted to a layout that already has the form and you cannot create several forms in it, thus forbidding you to isolate hidden fields to be sent or not sent.

ORIGINAL TEXT OF THE POST:

one value has to be hidden from the user and another has to be displayed.The hidden value is retrieved from the database and the displayed one is statically assigned value?

Comment: Question is not clear, do you want to set value property of a submit button?

Comment: I think you confuse value with caption (the text that is written on top of the button). Could that be true?

Comment: Nope not a caption! @DrCopyPaste

Comment: Yes exactly...But want to set two values, among those one has to be hidden whose value is retrieved from the database and another has to be displayed to the user which is assigned statically. I can use button element/tag but doesn't work in IE8!! @developerCK

Comment: Why don't you use a & for combining the values as you would do in an url.
I've tested this and it works.

e.g. <button type="submit" name="subAction" value"="addOne&product=6789">+1</button>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`data-` attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

```
<button type="submit" name="buttonname" data-value="value2" value="Value1">value</button>
```

then use [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute)  live  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d5kxL37e/)

```
var buttom = document.querySelector("button");
var dataValue = buttom.getAttribute("data-value");

alert(dataValue);
```

this way you can set as much value as you want just by add `data-*`

the best part is you can use

```
<input type="submit" name="buttonname" data-value3="value3" data-value="value2" value="Value1" />
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d5kxL37e/2/) if you don't like `button`

Comment: I tried to use `onclick="someFunction(this.data-value)"` on the button, but this did not work. Do you know why?

Comment: @SajibAcharya  use `onclick="someFunction(this.getAttribute('data-value'))"`

Answer (score 7):

Yes, by using a different tool.

```
<button type="submit" name="buttonname" value="hiddenvalue">Shown Value</button>
```

Comment: The problem is this <button>element doesn't work in IE8! :(