# How to set two values to one html button

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm working on a page where i'm rendering data from an api, where i make dynamic profile cards. And on clicking the button inside the card i'm calling an api through ajax. my problem is i need two values to pass to req.body to make the ajax success. I mananged the api call using one data using this code,

```
<div class="container" id="bb1">
        <% locals.posts.rows.forEach(function (patient) { %>
            
            <div class="patient-data">
              <div >
                <div style="padding-left: 100px"> <img src="<%= patient.dp %>" style="width: 45%;">  </div>
                <br>
              <div style="text-align: center;">
                <h5> P.ID : <%= patient.p_id %></h5>
                <p>  Name : <%= patient.patient_name %></p> 
              </div>
                <div style="padding-left: 110px;margin-bottom:20px ;"> 
                  <button type = "button" id="<%= patient.p_id %>" onclick="approve(this.id)" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="btn-success" style="background-color: #D1B147;"> View</button> </a></div>
              </div>
                </div>
        <% }); %>
      
    </div>
```

then inside my script;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function approve(id) {
      var p_id = id;
      console.log(p_id);
      var data = {};
      data.p_id = p_id;

      $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
             contentType: 'application/json',
             dataType: 'json',
             url: "http://localhost:5000/mData",                      
             success: function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
                 localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(data));
                window.location.href = 'mastersessionhistory';
                },
                
              error: function(){
                alert("Error")
                console.log('error occured')
              }
        })
   }    
 </script>
```

using this i was able to hit api and return values. i needed only the p_id to hit api. But now i have new key m_id to so my req.body should be {p_id,m_id}. How to include m_id on that bitton click so that i can call the api.
can i use this

```
<button type = "button" id="<%= patient.p_id, patient.m_id%>" onclick="approve(this.id)" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="btn-success" style="background-color: #D1B147;"> View</button> </a></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I set two values for a submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236210/can-i-set-two-values-for-a-submit-button)

Comment: Have you tried using a form with named inputs?

Comment: I  don't need a form submit for this. i just need to take values from the patient function and add this value to button

Comment: `approve(p_id, m_id)` ? You can pass more than one argument to a function. Or you can also pass an object. Also, why this complicated `id="<%= patient.p_id, patient.m_id%>"` with a comma and a space in it? Not even sure if this is allowed, and if it is, good luck selecting this id with CSS or JS

Comment: @JeremyThille bro can i use   id="<%= patient.p_id , patient.m_id %>" onclick="approve(this.id)"  ?

Comment: Yes, I understood your original question; you have this code and it doesn't work. Now what about my comment above, my suggestion and my question?

Comment: guys i got it  id="<%= patient.p_id  %>,<%= patient.m_name  %>"   this works